# laravel 10 multiple image uploads

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

laravel 10 multiple image uploading not working gives me a error

[error msg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4tCBG.png)

the code works fine when i modify the code to do it with one picture

[Controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bhnD1.png)
[View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k4nYi.png)

```css
   <form action="/addbg" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                @csrf
                    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
                                    <label for="formFileMultiple" class="form-label">Add Background Images</label>
                                 
                                <input class="form-control" type="file" name="imageid[]" multiple>
                  <br>*Select at least 3 images
<br><br>
 <p><input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" role="button"></input></p>
</form>
```

```html
class siteconfigcontroller extends Controller
{
    public function store(Request $request): RedirectResponse
    {
        //foreach (($request->file('imageid')) as $imageid){}
       foreach($request->file("imageid[]") as $key => $image){
    //$image = $request->file('imageid[]');

    $namegen=hexdec(uniqid());
    $imgextension=strtolower($image->getClientOriginalExtension());
    $imgname=$namegen.'.'.$imgextension;
    $up_location='image/bg/';
    $lastimg=$up_location.$imgname;
    $image->move($up_location,$imgname);
        }
     return redirect('siteconfig');
    }
   
        
}
```

Can someone figure this out for me

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551), images are hard to read and troubleshoot. Please [edit] your post and add the code here as text. Be sure to take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: `$request->file("imageid[]")` is wrong, it should be `$request->file('imageid')`; the `[]` is used on the front-end to denote it as an array, so `$request->file()` will be and array of files, or `null`. You should also do `foreach($request->file('imageid') ?? [] as $key => $image)`; that `?? []` will handle when no images are uploaded, and won't trigger an error.

Comment: `$request->file('imageid', [])` can also be used instead of `$request->file('imageid') ?? []`

Comment: @TimLewis Hey thank you very much i just figured what's happening after reading your comment

Answer (score 0):

### Tested 100% working

When you send array of inputs with HTML. You should not use the `[]` in name of input!

You can simply loop through it using a `for` and grab every file out of it.

**But there is a note about array files in laravel you cannot use `foreach` to loop through them! Just use a `for` loop as I did:**

```php
class siteconfigcontroller extends Controller
{
    public function store(Request $request): RedirectResponse
    {
        $images = $request->file('imageid', []);
        for ($i=0;$i<count($images);$i++){
            $image = $images[$i];
            $namegen=md5(uniqid());
            $imgextension=strtolower($image->getClientOriginalExtension());
            $imgname=$namegen.'.'.$imgextension;
            $up_location='image/bg';
            $image->store($namegen, $up_location);
        }
     return redirect('siteconfig');
    }      
}
```

Comment: Instead of *"Try this:"* followed by a code dump, explain ***why*** they should try this. I know what you're suggesting here, and it's almost correct (see my comment above re: `?? []`) but it might not be immediately apparent to the person asking the question.

Comment: you're right I just answered with my phone and I would explain later, I came to edit and explain and saw your comment. but thanks for advice.

Comment: @TimLewis Updated the answer and tested it. Is it correct now?

Comment: I mean that would work, but a `foreach()` is actually more appropriate. You probably ran into an issue with `$request->file('imageid')` returning `null`, which would be `foreach(null as ...)`, which is not valid. Mine and Aynber's comments handles that though, so a moot point. Also, sidenote, I wasn't the one who downvoted your answer 

Comment: @TimLewis First, null is beacuse of the `[]` in the name! Second, no, I tested, Laravel give a uploaded file instance and foreach cant iterate over it! You should treat it like an array to work! tried it with a live laravel locally and 100% sure about it!

Comment: Yes, I know that, but if you don't upload any files, then `$request->file('imageid')` **would be `null`**, and `foreach(null as $key => $image)` is not valid. If you upload files, then `$request->file('imageid')` would be an Array of `FileUpload` instances, and `foreach(...)` would work fine. I think your answer will still have issues, since `count(null)` is also not valid... Both of our comments are how to handle that, but nothing to do with `'imageid[]'`; that is wrong in **all cases**.

Comment: There you go; `$images = $request->file('imageid', []);` is correct; and now `count()` (or `foreach()`, etc.) won't fail if no images are uploaded  I'd argue that `foreach()` is still a better approach syntax-wise, but again, a `for()` will accomplish the same thing here.

Comment: No problem! Thank you for taking the time to follow-up with these comments and improve your answer; that is 100% the right step towards providing good answers on Stackoverflow  

Comment: I always update my answers when I find out about a new point relative to my old answers! Thanks for your time and encourage indeed.